# mysql query to Get result between the two given dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL server which is between the two given dates at present I am executing these query getting desired results & so much fruitful:

```
SELECT mdn,recharge_status_code, recharge_status_code_desc, date_time
FROM impressions_log 
WHERE recharge_status_code in ('515') 
AND date(date_time) IN ('2014-05-18','2014-05-19','2014-05-20','2014-05-21','2014-05-22')
```

I am also able to find one more query solution but it’s neither giving any error nor any result:

```
SELECT mdn,recharge_status_code, recharge_status_code_desc, date_time, retry_status
FROM impressions_log 
WHERE recharge_status_code IN ('515') AND date(date_time) = DATEDIFF('2014-05-18','2014-05-24')
```

Comment: `BETWEEN` might be helpful...

Comment: try with `between date1 and date2`

Comment: How do you know any rows match your conditions?

Comment: Can you plz share some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    mdn,
    recharge_status_code,
    recharge_status_code_desc,
    date_time,
    retry_status 
FROM impressions_log 
WHERE recharge_status_code in ('515') 
    AND DATE(date_time) BETWEEN '2014-05-18' AND '2014-05-24';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are sequential, you can either change your query to use `BETWEEN` or use `>` and `<` accordingly.

```
SELECT mdn,recharge_status_code, recharge_status_code_desc, date_time
FROM impressions_log 
WHERE recharge_status_code in ('515') 
    AND date(date_time) BETWEEN '2014-05-18' AND '2014-05-22'
```

Or:

```
SELECT mdn,recharge_status_code, recharge_status_code_desc, date_time
FROM impressions_log 
WHERE recharge_status_code in ('515') 
    AND date_time >= '2014-05-18' AND date_time < '2014-05-23'
```

I prefer the later as you don't have to do any casting.